# Column re-alignment in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, alignment, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to re-align columns in bootstrap, but so far unsuccessfully. This is how it appears in desktop view which is fine [desktop view](http://f.cl.ly/items/2C2x2Q2v1G3G1p2x3W3K/header.PNG). Here is how it looks when condensed in size [tablet view](http://f.cl.ly/items/400u2N0J333G1Z1G1t3Z/header1.PNG). I would like the owner gateway column to swap places with the logged in column.

html:

```
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-3" id="logo">
    <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/2B2c3t3d0N0r1F0F1m05/logo-white.png" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-lg-6" id="main-title">
    <h1 class="title">Owner Gateway</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 " id="logged-in">
    <p class="logged">Logged in as Mr Jones</p>
    <p class="log">Log out</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a guideline on this at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you read up on [column ordering in the Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering).

On the "owner" div, use the class `col-sm-push-4` to "push" it to the right, and similarly on the "logged in" div use the class `col-sm-pull-4` to "pull" it to the left.

Answer (score 0):

How abt this one :-

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" id="logo">
    <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/2B2c3t3d0N0r1F0F1m05/logo-white.png" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" id="main-title">
    <h1 class="title">Owner Gateway</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" id="logged-in">
    <p class="logged">Logged in as Mr Jones</p>
    <p class="log">Log out</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but doesn't set the columns the way that i want them when the screen size is reduced.